# Special character (utf-8) in a django jsonresponse

Tags: json, django, utf-8, python-3.5

Im using json response in django, but I have special characters (ñáé etc...)

my view

```
   def get_agencies(request):
        qr = Agency.objects.all()
        qr_jason = serializers.serialize('json',qr)
        return JsonResponse(qr_jason, safe=False)
```

But if I enter a special character like ñ in the json I recieve the ascii equivalent. Actually I can make a dictionary and then make the JasonResponse with the dictionary and it works, I can't find a way to use the serializers.serialize with utf-8.

json recieved (the u00f1 are ñ)

```
// 20170124165944
// http://localhost:8080/get_agencies/

"[
  {
    \"model\": \"items.agency\",
    \"pk\": 1,
    \"fields\": {
      \"name\": \"asdk\\u00f1ld\",
      \"tipo\": \"librevile\",
      \"adress\": \"laslkfdli323,
      ls\\u00f1\\u00f1\",
      \"phone\": \"56549875\",
      \"web\": \"http: //www.systmatic.com.mx\",
      \"lat\": 23.514646,
      \"lng\": -26.152684,
      \"created\": \"2017-01-24T00: 56: 28.302Z\",
      \"last_updated\": \"2017-01-24T22: 22: 08.856Z\"
    }
  }
]"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that you wrote that you would like to serialize using `django.core.serializers.serialize` but... you could do a workaround and serialize using `json` standard lib.

```
import json

def get_agencies(request):
    qr = Agency.objects.all().values()
    qr_json = json.dumps(list(qr), ensure_ascii=False, default=str)
    return JsonResponse(qr_json, safe=False)
```

I've added `default=str` parameter to `json.dumps` because I saw that you have a datetime field in your model, so that should take care of that issue.

Comment: Yeah, that works, also using dictionaries works, with the object.__dict__ method (now I'mk actually using this solution). I just was wondering if there is some way to use the serializers.serialize with special characters.

Answer (score 6):

Faster solution:

```
def get_agencies(request):
    qr = Agency.objects.all().values()
    qr_list = list(qr)
    return JsonResponse(qr_list, , safe=False, json_dumps_params={'ensure_ascii':False})
```